# "Visual Studio Online" for 2010 version?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, git, tfs, azure-devops

I am talking about the Visual Studio Online Source Control service by Microsoft. They now support Git as well.

I know they work fine on VS 2013, but is there a way to get it to work on 2010?

It worries me on using their service because what if a new vs studio release, such as vs 2014, and then I would need to upgrade to vs 2014 to be able to continue using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997788.aspx) you can use [Team Explorer 2010 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=23691) and the [Compat GDR](http://www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=29082) to enable connecting to Visual Studio Online from Visual Studio 2010.

In the past Microsoft has released compatibility updates for previous versions of Team Explorer to connect to the current version of TFS. That's not a guarantee for the future, but it has been the case for the last three releases.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That Compact GDR made it work. I hope they provide support for 2014/2015 version of VS studio. I think 2010 is the best. 2012/2013 is too slow.